# Updating graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on creating a graph that updates when a button is clicked, however when clicking the button, it seems only the axis are updating, and not the data itself.

The current version is in this plunker, I've also attached the code below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/85H6i25YPbTB0MRKtpZn?p=preview

I'm still quite new to D3 and have used a a few books and a lot of reading to get me to an ok level, but am struggling to find an answer to this specific question after trawling through many pages of the internet.

It would be amazing if anyone could give me some guidance on where I'm going wrong.

```
<body>
      <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
      <div id="option">
        <input name="updateButton" type="button" value="Click here to update the chart with results after the snap election" onclick="updateData()" />
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //graph 1

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .paddingInner(0.1);

    var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
      .padding(0.05);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .range(["#0087dc", "#d50000", "#FDBB30"]);

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
      for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
      return d;
    }, function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

      x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.Year;
      }));
      x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d3.max(keys, function(key) {
          return d[key];
        });
      })]).nice();

      g.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)

      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + x0(d.Year) + ",0)";
        })
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) {
          return keys.map(function(key) {
            return {
              key: key,
              value: d[key]
            };
          });
        })

      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x1(d.key);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return z(d.key);
        });



      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 2)
        .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
        .attr("dy", "0.32em")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text("Seats before snap election");

      var legend = g.append("g")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", 10)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(keys.slice().reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
        });

      legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width - 19)
        .attr("width", 19)
        .attr("height", 19)
        .attr("fill", z);

      legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", width - 24)
        .attr("y", 9.5)
        .attr("dy", "0.32em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });

    });

    // ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
    function updateData() {

      //call data
      d3.csv("data_copy.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
        for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
        return d;
      }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

        //scale range of data again
        x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.Year;
        }));
        x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d3.max(keys, function(key) {
            return d[key];
          });
        })]).nice();

        var sel = svg.selectAll("g")
          .data(data);
        //remove
        sel.exit().remove("g");

        sel.enter().append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + x0(d.Year) + ",0)";
          })
          .selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) {
            return keys.map(function(key) {
              return {
                key: key,
                value: d[key]
              };
            });
          })


        //remove
        svg.selectAll("rect");
        sel.exit().remove("rect");

        sel.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x1(d.key);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return height - y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return z(d.key);
          });

        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", 2)
          .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
          .attr("dy", "0.32em")
          .attr("fill", "#000")
          .attr("font-weight", "bold")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .text("Seats after snap election");
      });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@thedude's answer is right, but doesn't correct everything: it updates the bars, but the heights are wrong, for instance. Something to do with the inner .data join and the subsequent secondary formatting, I guess.

I checked at the same time and came up with the solution below. The core change that makes the update button update is this:

```
    var sel = svg.selectAll("g.chartarea").selectAll("g.year").data(data);
    sel.exit().remove();
    sel.enter().append("g").classed("year", true);
    // continuing with sel didn't update the just appended elements
    // so I repeated the selection to get the new elements as well
    sel = svg.selectAll("g.chartarea").selectAll("g.year");
    sel.attr( // and so on
```

Complete script:

```
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .paddingInner(0.1);

    var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
      .padding(0.05);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .range(["#0087dc", "#d50000", "#FDBB30"]);

    // added class to enable precise selection
    g.append("g").classed("chartarea", true);

    // added classes to enable precise selection
    g.append("g")
      .classed("axis", true)
      .classed("x-axis", true);

    // added classes to enable precise selection
    g.append("g")
      .classed("axis", true)
      .classed("y-axis", true);

    updateGraph("data.csv");

    // ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
    function updateData() {
      updateGraph("data_copy.csv");
    }

    function updateGraph(file) {

      //call data
      d3.csv(file, function(d, i, columns) {
        for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
        return d;
      }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

        //scale range of data again
        x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.Year;
        }));
        x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d3.max(keys, function(key) {
            return d[key];
          });
        })]).nice();

        var sel = svg.selectAll("g.chartarea").selectAll("g.year")
          .data(data);
        //remove
        sel.exit().remove();

        // added classes to enable precise selection
        sel.enter().append("g").classed("year", true);
        sel = svg.selectAll("g.chartarea").selectAll("g.year");
        sel.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + x0(d.Year) + ",0)";
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x1(d.key);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return height - y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return z(d.key);
          });

        var parties =
          sel.selectAll("rect.party")
          .data(function(d) {
            return keys.map(function(key) {
              return {
                key: key,
                value: d[key]
              };
            });
          });

        parties.exit().remove();
        // added classes to enable precise selection
        parties.enter().append("rect").classed("party", true);
        parties = sel.selectAll("rect.party");
        parties.attr("x", function(d) {
            return x1(d.key);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return height - y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return z(d.key);
          });

        // select the axes instead of appending them here
        g.selectAll("g.x-axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

        g.selectAll("g.y-axis")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", 2)
          .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
          .attr("dy", "0.32em")
          .attr("fill", "#000")
          .attr("font-weight", "bold")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .text("Seats after snap election");
      });

    }
```

Added some further changes that may be worth a look:

- Don't differentiate between initialization and update. This is exactly what D3 excels at: doing everything with the same code. In my refactored version, the code is reduced to a single updateGraph function that does both.
- Use classes or identifiers to differentiate your graphical elements. There are several places where you select too much with `selectAll("g")` which will select nearly all elements in your chart.
- Don't add stuff multiple times. For example, the axes should be added only once. In the original code, they were added twice, overlaying each other. Instead, add them once, leave them uninitialized, then later select them and set their attributes correctly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me and to correct my code.

As I'm still getting the hang of d3 the advice at the end is invaluable. I didn't realise that d3 could do all of this with the same code, or that I could just add the axes once and update them. I've still got a lot to learn, but taking the time out to give me this advice will save me time in the long run!

Comment: That's why we're doing this here. :-) Be sure to check out thedude's Plunker as well. He makes some other valuable suggestions, like naming or the .merge() function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your rect selection in your click handler like this:

```
        ...
        //remove
        sel = svg.selectAll("rect");
        sel.exit().remove("rect");

        sel.enter().append("rect")
        sel.attr("x", function(d) {
            return x1(d.key);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
          })
       ...
```

You can see it in action here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3R9lauiQQIB0IgrAk3X2?p=preview

*Edit - I've updated the plunker with a working example that addresses several other issues*

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I'll trawl through the code a bit later to see the other additions you've made.

I know you've already done a lot of work on this, but could I ask how I'd add a transition for the axes and bars if I wanted to?

Comment: Don't worry about answering this! I figured it out. Thank you so much for the help!